# Create array with data from different loop Javascript

Tags: javascript

i'm doing this, i want to assign to one ticket, data:

```
var recent = [];

for (i = 0; i < data.data.users.length; i++) {
    var userid = data.data.users[i].id;
    recent[userid] = "name":data.data.users[i].name;
}

for (j = 0; j < data.data.tickets.length; j++) {
    var requesterid = data.data.tickets[j].requester_id;
    var created_at = data.data.tickets[j].created_at;
    var tickettitle = data.data.tickets[j].subject;
    var ticketstatus = data.data.tickets[j].status;
    var arrayRef = recent[requesterid] || [];
    recent[requesterid] = arrayRef.concat([{
            "date": created_at,
            "titre": tickettitle,
            "status": ticketstatus,
            "tag": tag,
            "id": requesterid

        }]);
}
```

Some explanation: userid and requesterid are the same value.

I would like to add "name" in my array but "name" is contain in the previous loop so it cause trouble. 
can you help me pls ?

At the end i would like something like that:

```
[
O:{name:"test",date:"mydate",status:"mystatus",tag:"tag",id:"007"}
1:{name:"test2",date:"mydate2",status:"mystatus2",tag:"tag2",id:"0072"}
]
```

Comment: Please show the input array(s) and expected output array that results from those inputs.

Comment: what means `recent[userid] = "name":data.data.users[i].name;`?

Comment: just wanted to show you that i want to push `data.data.user[i].name` if `userid` is the same as `requesterid`and call it "name" in my array

Comment: @David Thomas i edit my post to show you what i expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is not making any sense (also syntax may be wrong)

```
recent[userid] = "name":data.data.users[i].name;
```

if you want to `add "name" in my array`

then

```
recent[userid] = { "name": data.data.users[i].name }; //now recent is an array of object
```

or simply

```
recent[userid] = data.data.users[i].name;
```

Now you need to use a different array than `recent` for the second loop

```
var recentArr = [];
for (j = 0; j < data.data.tickets.length; j++) {
    var requesterid = data.data.tickets[j].requester_id;
    var created_at = data.data.tickets[j].created_at;
    var tickettitle = data.data.tickets[j].subject;
    var ticketstatus = data.data.tickets[j].status;
    var arrayRef = recentArr[requesterid] || [];
    recentArr[requesterid] = arrayRef.concat([{
            "date": created_at,
            "titre": tickettitle,
            "status": ticketstatus,
            "tag": tag,
            "id": requesterid
            "name" : recent[requesterid] 
        }]);
}
```

Last line can be changed to (avoid creating an array for concatenation)

```
    recentArr[requesterid] = recentArr[requesterid] || [];
    recentArr[requesterid].push ({
            "date": created_at,
            "titre": tickettitle,
            "status": ticketstatus,
            "tag": tag,
            "id": requesterid
            "name" : recent[requesterid] 
        });
```

Comment: i get this following error:  TypeError: arrayReff.concat is not a function and if i use the `push`function i get the same error

Comment: @moskitos that is because `recentArr[requesterid]` has not been initialized to an array. Use the last option I have suggested.

Comment: i get this recentArr[requesterid].push is not a function

Comment: @moskitos made some changes, please check again

Comment: this is normal it's not working because just before we define this: `recent[userid] = { "name": data.data.users[i].name };`and then  `recentArr[requesterid] = recentArr[requesterid] || [];`so at this point `recentArr[requesterid]`is not an array but is equal to a string and push method not work on string am i wrong ?

Comment: Yes but I have changed the line to use only the second array